# Is it possible to send feedback via android sdk without user's email (anonymous)?

Tags: android, email, user-feedback

I have always wanted to be able to have my users send feedback to my email address. Not a problem when using 'createChooser()' with `ACTION_SEND` type within an `Intent`. This may lead to a few very rare errors where there is not an application on the user's device to handle that Intent.

My question is: Is it possible to send an anonymous "from" to my developer email account so the User's email will not be required? I know basic HTML, and am wondering if this is possible with a 'form' in a 'WebView' (preferably less complicated) I Do not have a web server or access to one, and am only an individual developer, so that may throw that out of question.

Any insight is greatly appreciated, thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a reasonably easy way to do this with `Intent`s. The best way I can see is have a couple of `EditText`s for the message and maybe a title, and then a send `Button` at the bottom, then sending programmatically with a java class.

See this link for some info on how to do the actual sending part: http://www.developerfusion.com/code/1975/sending-email-using-smtp-and-java/

It's fairly straightforward.

Comment: What is the smtp socket and host name? I don't have a server unfortunately. Just want to incorporate feedback directly to my email, without the user having to provide their email address (or accessing a separate app to handle it).

Comment: @MattMatt Matt, I think that's getting into a whole different question. I did my best to answer what you asked, which is whether it's reasonably doable to send an anonymous email directly from the app. The link I provided gives a solution. Without a server, I'm really not sure, nor do I have the expertise to advise you further - maybe that could be a new question. The bottom line is that as far as I know, there isn't an easy way to do what you want to do.